# I need to configure Outlook and Thunderbird to send/receive

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, encryption

I need to setup an Outlook system to send encrypted email attachments to a Thunderbird email client.  I don't need to encrypt email the other direction.  What steps do I need to follow to make this happen?  I don't know the version of Outlook but believe it is at least 2003 or later.  Thunderbird version is current.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have systems and software at hand to experiment and create precise instructions on your behalf, but I believe you could accomplish your need with [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/): [GPG4Win](http://www.gpg4win.org/features.html) on the Outlook end, and [Enigmail](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/enigmail/) on the Thunderbird end.